# What is indexing means neo4j and how it effects performance

Tags: neo4j

I have a idea of indexing in rdbms but can't think how indexing works in neo4j and also what is schema indexing?

Answer (score 2):

To quote from neo4j's free book, [Graph Databases](https://neo4j.com/graph-databases-book/):

> Indexes help optimize the process of finding specific nodes.
>
> Most of
>   the time, when querying a graph, we’re happy to let the traversal
>   process discover the nodes and relationships that meet our
>   information goals. By following relationships that match a specific
>   graph pattern, we encounter elements that contribute to a query’s
>   result. However, there are certain situations that require us to pick
>   out specific nodes directly, rather than discover them over the course
>   of a traversal. Identifying the starting nodes for a traversal, for
>   example, requires us to find one or more specific nodes based on some
>   combination of labels and property values.

That same book does an extensive comparison between neo4j and relational databases as well.

As for what the above-mentioned [indexes](https://neo4j.com/docs/developer-manual/3.4/cypher/schema/index/) (also known as "schema indexes") index: they index the nodes that have a specific node **label** and node **property** combination.

There is also a different indexing mechanism called ["manual" (or "legacy", or "explicit") indexing](https://neo4j.com/docs/java-reference/3.4/indexing/), which is now only recommended for special use cases.

[UPDATE]

As an example, suppose we have already created an index on `:Person(firstname)`, like so:

```
CREATE INDEX ON :Person(firstname);
```

In that case, the following query can quickly start off by using the index to find the desired `Person` nodes. Once those nodes are found, neo4j can easily traverse their outgoing `WORKS_AT` relationships to find the related `Company` nodes:

```
MATCH (p:Person)-[:WORKS_AT]->(c:Company)
WHERE p.firstname = 'Karan'
RETURN p, c;
```

Without that index, the query would have to either:

- Scan through *all* `Person` nodes to find the right ones, before traversing their outgoing `WORKS_AT` relationships, or
- Find all `Company` nodes, traverse their incoming `WORKS_AT` relationships, and compare the `firstname` values of every `Person` at the other end of the relationship.

Comment: example query- CREATE INDEX ON :Person(firstname)                                                                                                                          i guess after this query there will be a index created with this property as a reference but how and where this index will be used?